# How to print the current UI of Xamarin form crossplatform application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to print the current UI of a Xamarin.Forms cross-platform application. Are there any plugins or libraries available which support both android ios and uwp projects to do this? I'd really appreciate being pointed in the right direction to get started on implementing this kind of feature in my application.

Comment: https://blog.xamarin.com/native-printing-with-android/ maybe a starting point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this in two steps. Firstly you need to convert the current visuals into a printable file type. So assuming we are working with primarily mobile devices then we should make use of the 'screenshot' mechanisms.

There is a very good answer to another stack overflow account [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39234768/4486115) that guides you through setting up screenshots in xamarin forms using dependancy injection. The chaps answer is straight forward and easy to follow.

Once you have that screenshot as a png or jpeg etc. It's time to print it. There are a lot of threads on xamarins developer forums dedicated to the issues around printing from xamarin, a collection of these can be found [HERE.](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussions/tagged/printing)

So to start with it's worth mentioning that every platform xamarin forms (XF)supports has it's own mechanism for printing. XF does not provide any abstractions for printing in a cross-platform manner. You will need to write printing logic for each layer and expose it to XF using DependencyServices.

[Android Printing](https://blog.xamarin.com/native-printing-with-android/) - this is a link to printing in android.

[iOS Printing](https://medium.com/@dannyc/printing-pdf-image-with-uikit-uiprint-on-xamarin-ios-d8f24df0f215) - this is a link to printing in iOS ([Heres a sample app to help you as well.](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/RecipesAndPrinting/))

As I previously mentioned, because xamarin hasn't created a simple cross-platform mechanism for this in Forms, it's not quite as simple as you'd think and does require some work to implement. But none of the work is overly complicated, it uses standard dependancy patterns, it's really just the bulk of code required that can seem a bit daunting.

Comment: Is there is any reporting tools to produce data reports like invoices, sales reports available for xamarin.forms cross-platform application which supports on all the platforms. If those things are available that will be easy to take print out from those tools.

Comment: Not as far as I am aware, I haven't been able to track down any plugins that offer this functionality specifically. I honestly think you'd have to build it out as mentioned above. =)