# Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Map sa as image

Tags: xamarin, maps

I can`t find how to save map (Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Map) as image? There is common approach for iOS and Android? There is possible create implementation in common project?

Thanks for answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39234768/4984832

Comment: Thanks almost work :) but how i can extract Map from Activity.Window.DecorView;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved problem, that is working code

public class ScreenshotManager : IScreenshotManager
    {
        private readonly Activity _activity;

```
    public ScreenshotManager(Activity activity)
    {
        _activity = activity;
    }

    public async Task<byte[]> CaptureMapAsync(Map map)
    {
        if (_activity == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("You have to set ScreenshotManager.Activity in your Android project");
        }

        var renderer = Platform.GetRenderer(map);
        Platform.SetRenderer(map, renderer);

        var viewRenderer = renderer.View;
        var mapRenderer = (MapRenderer)viewRenderer;
        var mapView = mapRenderer.Control;

        var mapDownloaderTask = new TaskCompletionSource<byte[]>();
        mapView.GetMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback(m =>
        {
            mapDownloaderTask.SetResult(m);
        }));

        return await mapDownloaderTask.Task;
    }
}

internal class OnMapReadyCallback : Java.Lang.Object, IOnMapReadyCallback
{
    readonly Action<byte[]> handler;

    public OnMapReadyCallback(Action<byte[]> handler)
    {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    void IOnMapReadyCallback.OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        googleMap.Snapshot(new SnapshotMapCallBack(handler));
    }
}

internal class SnapshotMapCallBack : Java.Lang.Object, GoogleMap.ISnapshotReadyCallback
{
    readonly Action<byte[]> handler;

    public SnapshotMapCallBack(Action<byte[]> handler)
    {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public void OnSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            snapshot.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
            byte[] bitmapData = stream.ToArray();
            handler?.Invoke(bitmapData);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is an older question but i am facing same issue. Can you tell me where you have called `OnMapReadyCallback ` and `SnapshotMapCallBack ` because there is not any refrence for this function in this code