# Is there a way to capture a view and save it?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

We have many element(s) in a ContentPage. The goal is to take a picture of a specific element and then have access to that data - to save it or possibly other things such as cropping it.

So this question is twofold - is there a way to photographically capture a given element? Is there a way to do this if the element is not fully in view? Example a `ScrollView` would potentially have some of its elements not currently in view.

Our attempt at this is to use device specific screenshots and crop them to a given element. The screenshots are working, but we aren't having luck with cropping. Not to mention in the case as described above the screenshot will not work as the view isn't fully visible.

Is there a way to obtain the "graphical" (photo) data of an element at a given time even if it's not currently visible/partially visible?

Thanks for reading in advance.

Comment: Why would you try to get access to data via a Screenshoot? Is this some form of Desktop Automation? Manipulation of a third party programm?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://xamarinhelp.com/taking-a-screenshot-in-xamarin-forms/) and [this](https://gregshackles.com/generating-app-screenshots-using-xamarin-uitest/) articles, as well as at existing SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39234528/making-screen-capture-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: Why are you taking screenshoots of an application? If you control the application, just store the actuall data - not a screenshoot of the data in the UI - into whatever your backend it. Screenshoots are not a suiteable way to get data. It is even *less* suiteable for Documenting/storing inputs. | If you want to make a history of posts here as they are edited, would you a) Make images of the old posts or b) Just store the old posts - all data included - into a special "previous revisions" table? Hint: B is what everyone would pick.

Comment: If this is not your application but you still want to take screenshoots to "get data", what you are actually talking about is Desktop automation. | Everything about your question - including your resistance to explaining us the why - just sounds like you are neck-deep into a XY Problem. Taking a Screenshoot is your Y. But what is your X?

Comment: It is still odd. 1.If you want to share data Visually, you usually send the data and then have a UI there to dispaly it. Or just have teh same/a similar UI run on a seperate computer, accessing the same data source (propably a Databsae). 2. For rare cases like Toutorials you got Screenshoots you do manually with the Windows Snipping or Screenshoot and Manual cropping. 3. And for live teaching you Remote Desktop in View Only mode or Projectors. | What you are trying to do is either a XY Problem, a stupidly bad legal requirement, or you found a 4th case that I can not imagine right now.

Comment: Sending a image rather then the data in case 1 would be literal orders of Magnitude more data. And that is with JPG and similar lossy compression of the image. It will not scale on the storage or transmission side.

Comment: Oh a "we recieved your Contact Formular input, here is a copy for you" thing? That really only makes sense for a Web Formular, wich adds a whole layer of issues to this goal. But we are talking about Xamarian and Xamarian Forms, so it is clearly not a Web Page? Indeed to use this application, the user must have had to download your application. And if it is installed, it would be the ideal viewer for this data too or not? | Most people would just send it as plain old text.

Comment: Note that for pure formating, HTML is accepted. It is only dispalying images or loading stuff (even CSS) from a Server that has people up in arms. CSS can be embedded. Images could be embedded (actually HTML has a definition for that, using Base64 encoding of the image). But at least Outlock is known to not like that and display those as Attachments. And it also bloats the HTML/Mail size way past what aynone wants to see there,

Comment: @Christopher Yes exactly! A "here is a copy for you" situation perfectly describes it. Indeed Xamarin - correct not a web page. "A user must have this application installed" - Not exactly! We have in house users (our people) who will be using the application. They are taking in input from people who come to see them. Thus the people who will want their data are not actual users of the app. That's why we want to send them a screenshot of their data. Correct it is installed and it is the ideal viewer but the end users themselves aren't the people who want the data.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of talking, this is what I understand

1. The Users of your application are the Workers of Your company
2. The application is for managing the accounts of your companies Customers
3. The Customers have no access to their data, in any shape or form
4. Part of the Customer Data is their Email Adress
5. You want to send a copy of their Data to the Customers
6. As Emails do not allow formating that well, you want to send that Data as a Screenshot of the UI.

If I got all that right:

You are neck-deep in a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Or rather a ((XY)Y)Y Problem - a XY problem of the `3rd Generation`.

The obvious solution would be to **fix point 3 and give your customers access to their Data already**:

You can do that via a extra Programm, App, a Webpage or anything similar. If they can receive emails, they can download a app or open a Webpage and see their data there. May need a login, but nothing special. There are even ways to encode data/direct links into Emails and register your Programm with a custom Format. Indeed, that is how Steam Links on the Desktop work.

Meanwhile the In-House user get a "Customer Management" Programm that allows more direct access to the Customers Data in the Database (I asume you got a backend Database. But it is at least possible you do not).

If you can not fix Option 3 for stupid Boss/Legal Reasons (these are the only Valid reasons I can Imagine. And I can not stress enoug how stupid the boss would have to be in that), you should at least be able to fix at Point 5/6:

The first Option would be to send Text Emails. People often underestimate jsut how much is possible with pure Text. It is basically like writing on a Console, but even that is enough medium to make a [Art in it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art).

The other ways involve Managing the HTML limitations:

1. Save HTML Mail

The main security issue with HTML mails, is "downloading external content" part. Those operations can not be reliable scanned by Virus scanners and the like - especially in the age of HTTPS. Unless we talk about Kaspersky and the [stupid Idea they had](https://support.kaspersky.com/common/safemoney/12489#block4).

And even if they can be scanned reliable, even just the request of those files can be used for spam senders to verify the Email Adress is still in use. So it is a no-go too.

So you will need to Inline as much as possible. Inlining images is not that possible. While HTML totally has a Standart for that - you Base64 encode the binary into the HTML - this does not work reliably. At least Microsoft Outlook is known to interpret all Base64 images in the Email as Attachments - even the inlined ones. And even if they fixed this or it is no longer a relevant issue, inlining images tends to increase the HTML size significantly.

You can use CSS to some degree. But aside from inlining it, you might have to go back a step or two. In the end, Email Programms are really weak web-browsers. So they do not nessesarily support all the latest stuff instantly. Anything below CSS 3.0 should reliably work by now. But you better ask someone once you got more specific Requirements for this Email.

2. PDF Attachment

Somewhat more established is to create a .PDF file and send it. All those bills/other stuff in .PDF format you get - those have been created on demand from a Database, by the same code that also send the Email. In many cases the demand was automated too or the Sending Programm was a outright Background Process.

.PDF allows all Formating you could want. It can take up images inline. And there is plenty of ways to create .PDF from code. And as you can send it as a attachment, the Virus scanner has time to go over it. And we are not in the last Millenium, where a PDF Reader was a uncommon programm to have installed (I still remember the times when a current Version of Acrobat PDf Reader was delivered on every CD with a .PDF Format Handbook).

If you are stil dead serious about the whole "make a Image of the UI to send that", my only question is: How many Years have been aloted for that?